Smoothed and truncated Von Mangoldt function
The Von Mangoldt function $\Lambda : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$\Lambda (n)={\begin{cases}\log p&{\text{if }}n=p^{k}{\text{ for some prime }}p{\text{ and integer }}k\geq 1,\\0&{\text{otherwise.}}\end{cases}}.
$$
It is well known that
$$\Lambda(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \log\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).$$
The GPY sieve uses a truncated and smoothed version of the Von Mangoldt function, given by
$$\Lambda_R(n) := \sum_{d | n \\ d \leq R} \mu(d) \log\left(\frac{R}{d}\right),$$
for $R \in \mathbb{R}$.
What is the rationale behind the introduction of $\Lambda_R$? How is it derived? I can see that it is (piecewise) smooth in $R$ and that $\Lambda_R(n) = \Lambda(n)$ if $R \geq n$. So in this sense, $\Lambda_R$ is indeed a smoothed and truncated version of $\Lambda$. But I would like to understand better if there's anything special about choosing $\Lambda_R$ as an approximation for $\Lambda$. Where did it originate and how is it a good approximation for the original Von Mangoldt function $\Lambda$? (Do we have a good asymptotic or quantitative control of the error between $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda_R$?)
